# Awesomium 1.7 WPF WebControl to capture sites

Tags: capture, web-controls, awesomium

I'm trying out Awesomium v1.7.  The WebView seems easy to use but I am stuck with the WPF WebControl.

What I am trying to do is to capture the web page loaded in a WebControl.  The tutorial I found  (http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c-net/) is about v1.6 and WebView so I couldn't find the answer.

My specific problem is with the following line.  It says - Unable to cast object of type 'Awesomium.Windows.Controls.WebViewPresenter' to type 'Awesomium.Core.BitmapSurface'..

```
BitmapSurface surface = (BitmapSurface)aweWebControl.Surface;
```

Help please.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to know how to do this too.

Comment: I came across this, but it doesn't work.

http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/883/c-how-to-take-a-screen-shot-in-webcontrol.html